# roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch Failed to set USB interface

Tags: ros, usb, roslaunch, openni.launch, openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all

I have installed

ros-hydro-openni-launch

And when I run the command:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

I get the following error:

```
Image: PrimeSense/SensorV2/5.1.0.41: Failed to set USB interface!
```

And after running  dmesg | tail

```
[19250.592329] usb 3-6:  New USB device found, idVendor=1d27, idProduct=0600

[19250.612487] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0

[19250.612496] usb 3-6: Product: PrimeSense Device

[19250.612502] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: PrimeSense

[19250.613072] usb 3-6: Not enough bandwidth for new device state.

[19250.613091] usb 3-6: can't set config #1, error -28

[21923.567674] usb 3-6: USB disconnect, device number 27
```

Does someone have a clue?

In advance thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120681/roslaunch-openni_launch-openni.launch-failed-to-set-usb-interface/) by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 556 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found two possible solutions:

- `sudo modprobe -r gspca_kinect` as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/openni-dev/LZpcyCfh9UE)
- or deactivating xHCI and EHCI Hand-off in the bios as suggested [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/106036/asus-xtion-not-enough-bandwidth/)
- there is also some firmware update [from Asus](http://reconstructme.net/asus-xtion-usb-3-0-hotfix-2/) related to USB 3.0 problems

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [acp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1344/acp/) on 2014-01-22**:
Thank you Zdenek, I solved the problem by disabling the USB3 in the Bios and enabling USB2. I will later on try the firmware from Asus.